# Processing speed in google cloud vision api (much less under quota)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

We are running an application for label detection using cloud vision api. Application runs in 10 threads sending image urls to google cloud vision api, but we get google error code: 4  We can not access the URL currently. Please download the content and pass it in. When the application is run single threaded, we are not seeing this error messages as frequently as when it is run multi-threaded. Quota is 1800 requests / minute, but we seem to get a processing rate of 2.5/sec

Is there a way to increase the processing rate on google vision api end ?

tried changing consumer number on application and running multiple instance of the application (under different service accounts) without any success

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying images that are not in gcs. That error means Vision api was not able to download the public image you specified. If accessing your image, which is on the public internet, is too slow or inaccessible, you will get this error. It isn't related to quota.

The error message recommends downloading the image yourself from wherever it is and send the image into vision api as bytes instead of giving the url. Specify "content" instead of "source" in the [request](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/AnnotateImageRequest#Image).

Another option is you could move your images to a [GCS bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/).